# Rename the working directory

Tags: android, package

I want to rename the working directory for my android project.
for example tn.lordroid.project instead of tn.haythem.project.

When i try this: directly rename package, so i got errors. 
What is the best way to do this without errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Eclipse:

1. Right click on the project
2. Choose Android Tools > Rename application package

Comment: i got this error, when i try to run:
Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER

Comment: Check in your "AndroidManifest.xml" if all is done with the new name and remove the old application on your android device